# Fail to install gitlab on ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitlab

Now I am trying to install gitlab for ubuntu that be hosted on a virtual machine. Its version is 15.10 and it is 64-bit. I try to install it following this [tutorial](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu). But I got such error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gitlab-ce
```

The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab_gitlab-ce.list` is :

```
# this file was generated by packages.gitlab.com for
# the repository at https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce

deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ wily main
deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ wily main
```

Do you know how can I fix this issue? Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT:

After I installed a ubuntu with version of 16.04, the previous error does not exist anymore. But now a new one occurs :( 
When I run `apt-get install gitlab-ce`, I got the error of no avaliable space. I ran `df -Th` and here is the output

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     524M  7.7M  516M   2% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4      4.6G  4.1G  245M  95% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.6G   21M  2.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.6G     0  2.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs     524M   56K  524M   1% /run/user/1000
```

So there are some partitions that I can utilize. Do you know how to install the gitlab to those available partitions?

Comment: `apt update` and try again?

Comment: @AnthonySottile Do you mean `apt-get install update`? I have done that

Comment: No, I mean either `apt update` or `apt-get update` (probably with `sudo`)

Comment: @AnthonySottile After `apt update`, the error still exists

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems gitlab does not publish a deb for `wily` -- only for LTS releases (`trusty` / `xenial` at the time of writing), you *may* be able to sneak by with dropping the xenial (16.04) deb onto `wily` however as they are rather compatible distributions.  (but I would strongly suggest upgrading to an LTS release).

The directions to download and install a specific deb are listed on [this page](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu)

```
curl -LJO https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ce-XXX.deb/download
dpkg -i gitlab-ce-XXX.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but got such an error: `dpkg: error processing archive gitlab-ce-XXX.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-ce-XXX.deb
`

Comment: Do you mean replace `wily` by `trusty`?

Comment: You need to fill in XXX with some version as the installation instructions indicate (such as `9.2.5-ce.0`)

Comment: But the available package is with `ee` instead of `ce`. I tried `gitlab-ce_9.2.5-ce.0_amd64.deb` but it still doesn't work. The same error of no such file is still there

Comment: Here's one that worked for me: `https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ce_9.2.5-ce.0_amd64.deb/download`

Comment: Now I have installed ubuntu 16.04 and the previous error does not exist anymore. But I was told there was no enough space. I have edited the question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Your only usable partition is tiny! (The rest are tmpfs (essentially ram)) -- is this a virtual machine? can you expand the partitions?

Comment: Yes it is. When I add more base memory, now the space of `udev` increases to 5G. I wonder how can I move the space from `udev` to `/dev/sda1`? Suppose `/dev/sda1` is the noly usable partition, right?

Comment: Yep that's going to be the only usable one -- might be time to make a new virtual machine with a larger base disk (and probably choose `xenial` instead of a non-lts release!)

Comment: What do you mean by `base disk`. Is it `base memory`? I have already added it. And only the space of `udev` increased...

Comment: memory (RAM) != disk (udev is representing your *ram* as a tmpfs disk)

Comment: Oh, I got it... But the disk space is dynamically allocated, so it supposed can get more space when it needs?

Comment: At least with the one VM manager I've used (virtualbox) you can create a dynamically allocated disk, but it is a *fixed maximum size* -- I imagine your max is whatever the default is (which is pretty small)

Comment: Finally it works............Thanks a lot!!! you have saved my life.....

Answer (score 0):

https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce

```
If you are not comfortable installing the repository through a piped script, you can find the entire script here and select and download the package manually and install using

curl -LJO https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ce-XXX.deb/download
dpkg -i gitlab-ce-XXX.deb
```

try using a xenial package its just one ubuntu version higher.

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=9.2.5-ce.0
```

https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/xenial/gitlab-ce_9.2.5-ce.0_amd64.deb

or trusty (1 ubuntu version lower). Its been suggested that trusty has higher compatibility so you can try that first. But I agree that you should release-upgrade to ubuntu 16.04

https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/trusty/gitlab-ce_9.0.10-ce.0_amd64.deb

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce=9.0.10-ce.0
```